# \text{} in a fraction but spread over two lines

Tags: fractions, text-manipulation

Rather than try to describe in words or by way of a MWE, I have uploaded a picture of the desired result. I know how to create all the components (e.g. `\frac{}{} \text{}, ^{}`) of this fraction, except for the way in which each piece of text is over two lines.

Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A simple approach via environment `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
\frac{
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      some text\\
      here
    \end{tabular}
  \right)
  \times
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      some more\\
      here
    \end{tabular}
  \right)^a
}{
  \left(
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
      and even more\\
      text down here
    \end{tabular}
  \right)^b
}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

More elegant with environment `pmatrix` of package `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\frac{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \text{some text}\\
    \text{here}
  \end{pmatrix}
  \times
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \text{some more}\\
    \text{here}
  \end{pmatrix}^a
}{
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \text{and even more}\\
    \text{text down here} 
  \end{pmatrix}^b
}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: I'd just use `\parbox[b]{some width}{\centering ...}`

Comment: Environment `varwidth` of package `varwidth` avoids the knowledge of the exact width, but the struts of `tabular` or `array` have their advantages here.